# Create new dataframe conditional to the rows and columns of an existing dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
Name   CIN   EBV    GS    MSI
ab1    0.4   0.3   0.45   0.7
cd2    0.25  0.1   0.3    0.4
...    ...   ...   ...    ...
```

From that existing dataframe, I would like to create a new one which has new rows with the values of column A vs each other column name and its respective value from that existing one. Since I can not express myself much better than that and I know that this explanation is a bit messed up, here goes a draft of the output dataframe that I would like to obtain:

```
Name    C_S    P 
ab1     CIN   0.4
ab1     EBV   0.3
ab1     GS    0.45
ab1     MSI   0.7
cd2     CIN   0.25
cd2     EBV   0.1
cd2     GS    0.3
cd2     MSI   0.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `pd.melt`

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'])
  Name variable  value
0  ab1      CIN   0.40
1  cd2      CIN   0.25
2  ab1      EBV   0.30
3  cd2      EBV   0.10
4  ab1       GS   0.45
5  cd2       GS   0.30
6  ab1      MSI   0.70
7  cd2      MSI   0.40
```

Comment: Dind't know the existence of that command. It's pretty usefull and it works just fine for this propose! Thanks

Comment: @JoãoFernandes It's basically the opposite of pivot. For instance, to get from that `df`  back to your original you could do `df.pivot(index='Name', columns='variable')`

Comment: it makes sense. Thanks for your help, it was very helpfull!